# Which Mitzvot have their observance described in Tanach?

Tags: tanach, mitzvah

Despite the more or less direct reference to the 613 Mitzvos in the Torah, only a few of them are mentioned in the text explicitly to be observed in fact.

For example, Torah mentions Abraham circumcizing Itzhak and Ishmael or eating Matzah in the desert on the first Pesach or Boaz making [a sort of] Yibum.

Interestingly, I don't see the actual Mitzvos mentioned so often in Tanach.

Did anybody make a list of those? How many are there?

Comment: There's the nice one about a later king applying the verse from Deuteronomy and not punishing the children of those who committed treason.

Comment: "...mentioned in the text explicitly to be observed in fact." Do you mean "...mentioned in the text explicitly with an example of someone actually observing them in fact."?? Your wording seems to suggest that some mitzvos are written but are not required to be observed in practice?

Comment: @DavidKenner I'm saying that a lot of the 613 Mitzvos are debatable. But many Ms. are only hinted in the Torah and never mentioned performed, like Krishma or Teffilin. I would like to know what Ms are mentioned so I can be sure they were observed ever since.

Comment: So what do you do with shechita? It is not described, but it is directly mentioned? Also, do you agree with Robev's edit? I still think your q is unclear and needs better description as to what you are asking so far.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are looking for -- the chumash tells of having a king. Later, the Jews have kings. The text says that we don't eat the gid but no one is listed as not eating it. The torah talks about a concept of teshuva and David did teshuva. I don't get the parameters of your search.

Comment: @rosends You're on track - I'm not limiting it to something specific, but behaviors that someone did as a Mitzvah, that's explicit and not derived like saying "ויקח" means Kiddushin, or וישחטו means the Mitzvah of שחיטה.

Comment: Relevant for this time of year: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nehemiah.8.14?lang=he

Comment: @AlBerko Why is directly mentioned a prerequisite to being a mitzvah?

Comment: Can you pick a list of Mitzvos to work with? Rambam? Rav Saadya? Etc.